# JavaScript - Change color of text based on regular expression

Tags: javascript, css, regex

I'd like to be able to search the contents of a `textarea` (which will contain HTML markup that is visible to the user) with a specific regular expression that searches for specific attributes of all the HTML tags. Then I want to change the font color (within that same `textarea`) of the results of the search. Assume I have a submit button that will call a JS function that:

1. Creates a variable with the value of the `textarea`
2. Creates a variable with my regex search object
3. Searches the `textarea.value` with the regex string and changes the font color of all matches

Is this possible?

Comment: You can't change the font of a `textarea` partially. You have to go for a div with `contenteditable="true"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  But it will take some work.  More than likely, you'll need to swap out your textarea with a div and set its `contenteditable` attribute to true.  Then you can wrap matched words with a span and set the font-color for those spans.

[Rich text editing from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Rich-Text_Editing_in_Mozilla)

Comment: But it is not the same as `textarea` i.e. user will see html markup when doing edit, isn't it?

Comment: @caligula No.  The formatting will appear, not the HTML.  I'll add a link to MDN's article on it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have explained further - the textarea will originally contain HTML markup that is visible to the user. The regex will find all attributes of every HTML tag, and I'm wanting to change the font color of these search results (the HTML attributes). Will a div still be the way to go if I want to keep the HTML unparsed? I've added this to the question.

Comment: @Anthony If you want to color text that's already inside a textarea, there's no other way to do it but with rich text editing (RTE for short), because you can't do much more than type text into a textarea.  You can't color it or otherwise format it.  RTE, when done correctly, functions like a textarea on steroids, with formatting and images and tables and such.  Maybe I am misunderstanding your question.

Comment: @kevin628 Thanks for the information. I'm basically struggling to figure out how to keep the HTML markup unparsed in the editable div. But upvote for your help.

Comment: @Anthony You'll have to turn the angle brackets into HTML entity codes.  Like `&#60;` for left pointing bracket and `&#62;` for the right pointing bracket. Take a look at this table: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_ascii.asp (Yes, I know, cranky SO users. You guys don't like W3Schools, but this is a good, clear list.)